# Can I make a while-loop that uses RSI value as the condition?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, forex, mt4

When I try to run this `while`-loop in MQL4, it can not seem to update the **`rsi`** from within the loop. It always returns the same value of the `rsi` and thus stays in an eternal loop. I have tried it on an EA as well as a script.

I have also tried making `rsi` a globally defined variable too but still did not work.

```
void OnTick()
{

     double rsi = iRSI(NULL,0,14,PRICE_CLOSE,0);        // defining rsi
                 
     while( rsi < 50 )
     {
            double rsi = iRSI(NULL,0,14,PRICE_CLOSE,0); // update rsi 
            Sleep(10000);                               // slow down loop 
            Alert("this is from inside while loop rsi is "+rsi); 
     }
        
     Alert("While loop exited, condition met");         // now code goes
     Alert("opening an order now " );                   //     to place an order
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I make a `while`-loop that uses RSI value as the condition?

Oh sure you can.

Let's move out the colliding elements.

Given the code as-is, there are several brutal misconceptions to repair:

- if a code spends some time "inside" such a loop, there will never be heard a new incoming `QUOTE`-message from market, so your `Close[0]`-value will remain "blind" to any such update from Market.
- if a second **`double rsi = ...`** declaration takes place "inside" a scope of a `while`-loop-constructor, the newer versions ( Builds ) of the MQL4 language will actually "mask" the older ( "outer" ) variable, that is yet still used in the loop-constructor control variables / conditions. Result? You assign "new" values to an "inner"-variable, that bears just by coincidence a same name as the "outer"-variable ( both are named `rsi`, yet the "*inner*" keeps-masking the "outer", so the "outer" never gets any update(s), if any such were stored inside the loop into the "inner" )

### Solution

- avoid masking by not declaring any same-name named variables (always, it is a sign of good engineering practice)
- avoid receiving market-`QUOTE`-updates by deaf-loop-locking - prefer the non-blocking use of `if(){...}` instead of `while(){...}`

MQL4 is a responsive-ecosystem, where `OnTick()` is automatically called whenever a new `QUOTE`-message arrives from FX-Market, so design your algorithms so as these ***never block.***

For your learning-directed inspiration, you may try your next few steps using this template :

```
string MASK  = "[%s]_INF:: "                           // DEF. & INIT...
             + "This is a QUOTE# %5d "
             + "Having arrived at [%s]_FX-MarketTIME\n"
             + "|Ask %16.8f\n"
             + "|Bid %16.8f\n"
             + "|Vol %16d\n"
             + "|RSI %16.8f";
double rsi   = EMPTY;                                  // DEF. & INIT...
int   nTicks = 0;                                      // DEF. & INIT...

void OnDeinit( const int aDeinitReason )
{    EventKillTimer();
}

int  OnInit()
{    EventSetTimer( 1 );
     Comment( "------------------------------------------------------\n ",
                    "WAITING for a first QUOTE-arrival from FX-Market\n",
              "------------------------------------------------------"
               );
     return( 0 );
}

void OnTick()
{     nTicks++;                                        // update COUNTER
     rsi = iRSI( NULL, 0, 14, PRICE_CLOSE, 0 );        // update rsi
     Comment( SetupComment() );                        // update GUI

  // -------------------------------- FIRST 50 FX-Market Ticks delivered
     if ( nTicks < 50 ) return;

  // -------------------------------- AFTER 50 FX-Market Ticks delivered
  // --------------------------------       BE WARNED, THIS IS AN AWFUL ANTI-PATTERN
     while( True )
     {
            rsi = iRSI( NULL, 0, 14, PRICE_CLOSE, 0 ); // update rsi
            Comment( SetupComment() );                 // update GUI
            Sleep( 10000 );
     }
  // --------------------------------       NEVER GETS HERE
     Alert( "?" );
}

string SetupComment()
{      return( StringFormat( MASK,
                             TimeToStr( TimeLocal(),
                                        TIME_DATE|TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS
                                        ),
                             nTicks,
                             TimeToStr( TimeCurrent(),
                                        TIME_DATE|TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS
                                        ),
                             NormalizeDouble( Ask, 8 ),
                             NormalizeDouble( Bid, 8 ),
                             Volume[0],
                             NormalizeDouble( rsi, 8 )
                             )
               );
}

void OnTimer()
{    Comment( ChartGetString( 0, CHART_COMMENT ),
              "\n",
              TimeToStr( TimeLocal(),
                         TIME_DATE|TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS
                         )
              );
     Print(   ChartGetString( 0, CHART_COMMENT ) );
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you very much,  I am closer to figuring this out but have still been unsuccessful. I don't want to make you think I am ungrateful for your very detailed and educational answer but can you tie my shoe for me and give me an example please  >.< .

Comment: Oh by the way, I have basically already used a bunch of if statements in my EA's code and after them comes the while loop as a final condition which I think its actually needed in my situation. I don't think I can get away without it and still get what I want out of the code ....

Comment: Yes , so true , you are right and I have learned more too.  I appreciate this gift from you that I will try to incorporate and experiment with  . Thank you for teaching me and a wonderful teacher you are too!!

Comment: This is going to take me a good while to understand but I will go through it line by line and break it down . Thank you for your time . Anything I can do for you going forward  ??

Comment: Hi user3666197, long time no speak. I hope you are well. Just a quick reminder that posts should not give question-asking advice - you are welcome to give it, but it's best in the comments (under the question or under the answer, as here). Answers themselves should address a broad audience and not get bogged down in meta-commentary. (It's good advice though).

Answer (score -1):

Declare `rsi` only once, outside the loop, as you already have it.  To make it work as you intend REMOVE the type `double` from in front of variable `rsi` inside the loop.